# When is an exception considered as uncaught?

Tags: php, exception

Is an uncaught exception in a function still considered as uncaught if this function is placed in a `try-catch` block?

Will this example catch the exception properly or not and is it considered a proper way?

```
$a = Foo();

function Foo(){
  try {
    $result = Bar();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
  return $result;
}

function Bar(){
  Chnaps();
  return true;
}

function Chnaps(){
  throw new Exception("Some exception", 1);
}
```

Comment: That code won't  run without an error (albeit just `E_NOTICE`) since you `return $result` which is undefined (since you're catching the exception). In this case, `Foo()` probably shouldn't catch the exception and you'd catch it when doing `$a = Foo();`.

Comment: Didn't see that one. And now that there is an `exit` statement?

Comment: With the `exit` statement it'll run without errors and catch the exception. Just out of curiousity: Why don't you just try it yourself? Save that as a `.php` and run it?

Comment: I'm basecly wondering if the exception needs to be re-thrown in each function or if it just needs o be catched in the parent function.

Comment: In particular, see the first answer to that question.

Comment: Is one thanks didn't see!